# Two conditions for while loop. What's my error?

Tags: c++

I have a questoin. Everything here seems to work fine, besides the following line:

```
} while (OneMoreTime != 'y' || OneMoreTime != 'n');
```

Full Code;

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
int ARRAY_LENGTH = 5;
int MyArray[ARRAY_LENGTH] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

cout << "Values in the array: " << ARRAY_LENGTH << endl;

for (char OneMoreTime = '\0'; OneMoreTime = 'n'; )
{

    int WhichNumber = ARRAY_LENGTH;
    do  
    {
        cout << "What numbers from the array do you want to see, counting backwards? ";     
        cin >> WhichNumber;
    } while ((WhichNumber > ARRAY_LENGTH) || (WhichNumber <= 0));


    //calculating the correct position in the array (from start)
    int Number2Print = ARRAY_LENGTH - WhichNumber;


    //printing
    cout << "The number is: " << MyArray[Number2Print] << endl;


    //continue?
    do
    {
        cout << "One more time? (y/n) ";
        cin >> OneMoreTime;
    } while (OneMoreTime != 'y' || OneMoreTime != 'n');

}

return 0;
}
```

What I get is it constantly asks "One more time? (y/n)" after successfully printing the first time. If I just use one condition it will work (but that wouldn't be enough).

Comment: `(OneMoreTime != 'y' || OneMoreTime != 'n')` Isn't that always true?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That condition will always be true as `OneMoreTime` cannot be both equal to `n` and `y`. What you probably mean is to use `&&` (and)

```
while (OneMoreTime != 'y' && OneMoreTime != 'n');
```

Comment: Into C++ I see; *interesting* language. As is Italian ;)

Answer (score 0):

this statment 
while (OneMoreTime != 'y' || OneMoreTime != 'n');
is a false statment, what you will get is no matter what you put in is gonna return true and 
continue the loop.

A || B, if you put 'y' ,B is true, if you put 'n', A is true, so the 'or' operation will return true if either one of the condition is true.

if you using 
while (OneMoreTime != 'y' && OneMoreTime != 'n');
it will still put next value in the array if you input 'n'